# How do I control the fan on a Apple Mac Mini?

Tags: power-management

I am running 12.04 LTS on Apple mini hardware (about 4 years old).

The fan seems to run non-stop. "ThinkFan" is installed but I do not know how to use 
it in order to modulate fan speed. The software says that it can be used with systems other
than ThinkPads through sysfs hwmon interface. I have no idea what that is.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `fancontrol`. It might help.
You could then edit your config file `/etc/fancontrol` or run `pwmconfig` (`sudo su - -c /usr/sbin/pwmconfig`). You can also edit the config file like this one, but bear in mind that you have different hardware:
Taken from `https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_speed_control`

```
INTERVAL=10
DEVPATH=hwmon0=devices/platform/coretemp.0 hwmon2=devices/platform/w83627ehf.656
DEVNAME=hwmon0=coretemp hwmon2=w83627dhg
FCTEMPS=hwmon0/device/pwm1=hwmon0/device/temp1_input
FCFANS= hwmon0/device/pwm1=hwmon0/device/fan1_input
MINTEMP=hwmon0/device/pwm1=20
MAXTEMP=hwmon0/device/pwm1=55
MINSTART=hwmon0/device/pwm1=150
MINSTOP=hwmon0/device/pwm1=105


INTERVAL: how often the daemon should poll CPU temps and adjust fan speeds. INTERVAL is in seconds.
```

The rest of the configuration file is split into (at least) two values per configuration option. Each configuration option first points to a PWM device which is written to which sets the fan speed. The second "field" is the actual value to set. This allows monitoring and controlling multiple fans and temperatures.

```
FCTEMPS: The temperature input device to read for CPU temperature. The above example corresponds to /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_input.
FCFANS: The current fan speed, which can be read (like the temperature) in /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/fan1_input
MINTEMP: The temperature (°C) at which to SHUT OFF the CPU fan. Efficient CPUs often will not need a fan while idling. Be sure to set this to a temperature that you know is safe. Setting this to 0 is not recommended and may ruin your hardware!
MAXTEMP: The temperature (°C) at which to spin the fan at its MAXIMUM speed. This should be probably be set to perhaps 10 or 20 degrees (°C) below your CPU's critical/shutdown temperature. Setting it closer to MINTEMP will result in higher fan speeds overall.
MINSTOP: The PWM value at which your fan stops spinning. Each fan is a little different. Power tweakers can echo different values (between 0 and 255) to /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/pwm1 and then watch the CPU fan. When the CPU fan stops, use this value.
MINSTART: The PWM value at which your fan starts to spin again. This is often a higher value than MINSTOP as more voltage is required to overcome inertia.
```

There are also two settings fancontrol needs to verify the configuration file is still up to date. The lines start with the setting name and a equality sign, followed by groups of hwmon-class-device=setting, seperated by spaces. You need to specify each setting for each hwmon class device you use anywhere in the config, or fancontrol will not work.

```
DEVPATH: Sets the physical device. You can determine this by executing the command
```

You should have these values set accordingly to the values of the the command `sensors`.

Comment: I recommend expanding this answer to explain specifically how to use `fancontrol` for this purpose. Also, if you're unsure if it will work (or work well enough), I recommend including an explanation of the relevant issues.