# Does with ubuntu 15.04 the problem with fans on dell laptop is fixed?

Tags: dell, fan

I have a problem but there is a fix for that by installing i8kutils package, and adding some parametars for the fans to works properly.

And does this is fixed on 15.04?..

For those who doesnt know the issuse is about that the fans without this fix are working on max non-stop, and that is alot of noise ...

Thanks in afvance

Comment: You should mention your laptop model.

Comment: Try and you'll see...

Comment: I tired seems that is the same...

Answer (score 0):

You can try fancontrol. I've posted a solution here:

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/186426/how-do-i-control-the-fan-on-a-apple-mac-mini/614011#614011
```